# "service" vs. "systemctl" on running Docker container? With --privileged option?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, systemd, systemctl

I have a script (setup.sh) that removes any old tails of systemd inside `ubuntu:focal` Docker container and installs fresh ones:

```
set -e

apt-get update

apt-get install --yes apt-utils

apt-get install --yes language-pack-et net-tools systemd

rm --force \
  /etc/init.d/ondemand \
  /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/* \
  /lib/systemd/system/*getty*.service \
  /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/* \
  /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/* \
  /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/* \
  /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl* \
  /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev* \
  /lib/systemd/system/systemd-update-utmp*
find /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants -type l \
     ! -name systemd-tmpfiles-setup\* \
     -delete
systemctl set-default multi-user.target

rm --force /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d

apt-get install --yes rsyslog

apt-get clean
rm --recursive --force /var/lib/apt/lists/*

exit 0
```

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)
FROM ubuntu:focal

# Set up APT
COPY src/apt-sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list
COPY src/apt-local-options /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90local-options
COPY src/rc.local /etc/rc.local
RUN chmod +x /etc/rc.local

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

COPY setup.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN sh -x /usr/local/bin/setup.sh
```

And finally my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  tests:
    build:
      context: ./docker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: "test:latest"
    container_name: testc
    entrypoint: /lib/systemd/systemd systemd.unit=multi-user.service
    stop_grace_period: 1s
    tmpfs:
      - /run
      - /tmp
    volumes:
    - /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
version: '2.2'
```

I build and run Docker container using `docker-compose up -d --build tests`.
Double check with `docker ps` gives me:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXX   test:latest   "/lib/systemd/system…"   X   X   X   testc                                                  testc
```

Now when I execute `docker-compose exec --privileged tests service rsyslog status`, I got (exactly two times):

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Then, if I run without `--privileged`, everything works:

```
 * rsyslogd is not running
```

Why is that happening? As I understood, that `--privileged` just gives a Docker an access to your (host) OS and nothing more.

And second, and the most important question is that, when I run (with or without `--privileged` get same result):

```
docker-compose exec tests systemctl status rsyslog
```

I got:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Why is that happening, I have no clue?
Please note, that `docker-compose exec tests ps -p 1 -o comm=` gives me `systemd` as an output, so I consider, that systemd should be a PID=1.

My goal is to use `systemctl` and not `service`, since I should `apt-get install` custom `.deb` files into the Docker container, and these custom `.deb` files include instructions with `systemctl` commands.

UPD: please, don't advise me to use different approach in sense like `docker is not designed for systemd` etc. Since I can do that using `service`, then it is probably possible to do using `systemctl`, the question is how?!

Comment: systemd-in-docker is really not docker's preferred deployment model; there are alternate systemd-supported containerization tools available if you really want them -- see systemd-nspawn f/e -- but The Docker Way is to have each container directly run one service, not run an init system that eventually runs your service.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I do know that :), but still I wish to use that systemd-in-docker approach. If it is possible to do using `service`, then it is probably possible to do using `systemctl` and that's what I'm aiming

Comment: Maybe a full virtual machine is a better match for your needs than a single-process container.

Comment: @DavidMaze those containers will be brought up in Gitlab pipeline, so I have to stick with Docker solution. Note, that `service` command WORKS, why shouldn't `systemctl` :)?